# Amazon MWS and Microsoft Access for a DB Layman?

Tags: ms-access, amazon-mws

I have some experience in MS Access, but mostly only as an offline DB tool.

I have begun working with both Seller and Vendor Central at my new company, and am in charge of scrubbing the vast amount of data for trends and whatnot. At the moment our company is solely relying on exporting reports from Seller Central directly, and cross referencing documents. I was hoping to get us started with a rudimentary database hooked into Seller directly. Our company already has a MWS Developer ID, and I see an MWS Access Key and whatnot.

I'm surprised to not finding any resources as to how I should actually connect MWS to Access. I feel confident that I can find some success by dabbling with the API once I get it connected, but I can't actually find any references on how to actually establish that connection.

Any resources you guys can forward me? Maybe I'm searching for the wrong terms. Everything I search just comes up with data service companies advertising their tools.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the interface to AWS is going to  be  web service based. And access unfortantly does not have a built in web services interface.

So, your choices are:
Write some VBA code to hit/use/consume AWS web services. Web services are just that -a web API. (likly REST services.  REST is just a fancy term that you have to type in a given URL.

So, what you looking to search for?

How can I consume web based data in Access.

Say this answer on SO

[Making a SOAP request from Access 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764123/making-a-soap-request-from-access-2007/3764378#3764378)

The main issue is that Access does not have really good tools for consuming web data.

However, most web front "store" applcations tend to have a user area in which you can export the daily sales or data say to csv. You now can import that data into Access (or Excel).

And they often have a report area - you can generate a report, and then download again in some format like xml or csv (and again, import into Access or Excel).

If you don't want to have to maually import the data?

Then you have to code out web requests. And that can be painful.

This unfortantly means you can use say a linked table (ODBC) like you can for  Acces say to some database.

So, you can start to write web interface code (it will be SOAP or REST.

Believe it or not, there was a SOAP add-in tool kit for Access 2003. But,  no one used it, so they dropped it. (of course now 17 years later -gee, a truckload of people GET IT - and now see the need to consume web data!

So, you question and what to learn about?
You asking how does one consume web services.

Well, using a tool designed to work with web services helps a lot. (that's why I suggest Visual Studio and .net). If they have a WSDL for you? Then you can point Visual Studio at the web (WSDL), and it will crank out a set of "methods" and properites for you. (it will create a class. But then again, did you use and write class objects in VBA? (it does support you creating classes. But the SOAP tool kit (no longer avaiable) would write this code for you!

So, if you want to go beyond their built-in repoting tools (that let you export + download the data in some format like csv for use with Access or Excel)?

Then you have to write writing code to make web calls.

This is not a lot different in the past. If you wanted some data from the accounting system? Well, you can/could/usually do some export with the accounting package to spit out a csv file of some sort. You then import into Access.

However, if you had better skills, you might link up to the database from Access, using ODBC and then write some SQL queries against that data. So, it really comes down to skill level here. Some could not be bothered to learn say SQL and a query. So, they just export the data out of accounting, and then import into access.

The problem is now you can't link to that web site, and use SQL queries of data. You have to use web service calls. (at least if you want to make some of this process automatic).

So, you might be just fine by exporting data/files from the AWS services, and then just import into Excel or Access. As such, you not writing any code, and you just use the Access GUI to import data.

But, some want to just hit a button in Access, and see all the orders and sales from today - and have Access pull that data from the web site with one click.

For some simple data pulls? You could make a web call from Access. But for complex web interfaces? Then you need to use tools that support web interfacing (say like Visual Studio .net).

For a simple data pull? I'll use VBA and MSXML.
But, if the parameters and data call is complex? Then I write it in .net, and THEN expose that code as a consuming library to MS-Access.

So,  once you signed up for AWS and what ever web services? Then they will supply you with the web calls, and documentation. You then are free to use your programming tools of choice to interface. But, this can be quite a bit of work. So, you might use VBA, but .net is much better for this type of work. (and it also a lot more difficult to code out).

Answer (score 0):

As a developer who has done this, I would write a "sync" program that connects to MWS, pulls back your data, and then inserts that into MS Access.  In my case, it was a C# .NET Core app with SQL Server and I used the available MWS SDK that Amazon provides for free to handle all the API calls to MWS.  You can create a schedule so your app pulls the data on an interval, or make it manual where you push a button to sync it into your system.

Of course you can use Java or PHP instead of C#, or you can roll your own MWS API calls.  Or like you mention there are several third party vendors that have out-of-the-box ready solutions.

I haven't used MS Access in 20 years or so, so I'm not sure about calling MWS directly.  I would gather it could be done, but is probably too much work, but I could be wrong.  A .NET app can insert into MS Access, no problem, but also handle the HTTP calls to MWS for you.